# Order-invariant conjunctive queries are FO-definable without the order

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, db.databases, finite-model-theory, first-order-logic

I'm looking for a reference for Exercise 6.11 from Libkin's FMT [book](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/libkin/fmt/fmt.pdf):

> Prove that an order-invariant conjunctive query is FO-definable without the order relation.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you really looking for a *reference*, or just for a *proof*? If you need a reference to put in a paper, I don’t know any, but I wouldn’t hesitate to directly cite the Exercise in Libkin’s book. If you need a proof of the fact, it’s fairly simple.

Comment: I'm looking for the reference. I agree that the proof is quite easy (if I get it right).

Comment: A reference to some super-theorem from which Ex. 6.11 follows would be ok too.